# Which operation in BigInteger I can use

Tags: java, biginteger

I have bigInteger = 256 which is 100000000 in binary. What operations do I have to use to get the result 1 = 000000001 in binary?

EDIT:

```
BigInteger.valueOf(256).xxx = 1
```

Comment: Say what? Please explain a bit more, preferable with code.

Comment: `return bigInteger / 256` will do it - guessing that's not what you want, so you'll need to explain a bit more.

Comment: Do you mean you want to print 1 in binary with 8 leading zeroes?

Comment: What will this operation do with 64, 1568, and another example number you choose yourself? (@juergen d yeah, I was starting to lean towards bitshift, but on BigInteger?)

Comment: shift was the operations what I looking for I cant remember

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BigInteger newInt = new BigInteger("256").shiftRight(8);
```